# Unable to build In unity : "UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException:"

Tags: unity-game-engine, build-error

The project runs just fine but I am unable to build it using build settings.

Here's the error message:

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors   at
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
> (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002bb] in
> <2f1c602eae0d45c293fff3e3aef759fa>:0    at
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean
> askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions)
> [0x00080] in <2f1c602eae0d45c293fff3e3aef759fa>:0
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: when does this error get thrown? is it with every project? for what target system is it?

Comment: The error gets thrown when I try to build my project with an Android target System.It started to show up after i tried to implement Unity Ads into my project.And the error is only with this project since the other projects are being built successfully.

Comment: there are usually more helpfull errors further above in the console .. the two you posted are very general and not helpful

Comment: I got these errors when build to desktop. no solution found yet

Comment: This question and given answers here are not really helpful as they are all based on assumptions and semi-knowledge .. The errors OP shows us are just the final compiler messages for saying **there were errors** but they give absolutely no indication for **why/where** exactly. Whenever Unity fails due to compiler errors there usually appear further above in the console. Until we know these giving a helpful answer is impossible!

Answer (score 12):

[Problem Solved]

Just had to delete the "plugins" folder from the "Assets" folder of my project.

Comment: Prital Bamnodkar, I just would like to know why you can figure out this is the reason? Your answer saved me days!

Answer (score 5):

in unity unity 2018.3.1 check "use legacy SDK tools" (player settings >> publishing settings).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had to change the Player settings Build system from Gradle to Internal (Unity 2018.2.10f1)

[image]

Comment: thanks this worked!

Answer (score 2):

Just change the buildSystem from Gradle to Internal. I solved my problem with it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error message. The problem was that I tried to minify the android APK with 'Proguard'. Changing it to 'Gradle (Experimental)' in Player Settings did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In my case at least, I added a line to mainTemplate.gradle in dependencies { ... } (probably you don't have this file but in case some of you have) this line is:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.4'
```

The dependencies section become:

```
  dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.4'
**DEPS**}
```

I needed to add an implementation in it. The second line. Where I was wrong at I added a dumb `,` before that line. Because of that, It failed. If you put some `,` just delete it. I don't know it's gonna solve your problem but at my side it solved.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess many of the answers above are right for many different people, but in my case it was due to a stupid fault which I had expected unity to automatically ignore

```
using UnityEditorInternal;
```

So basically when I closed my script editor it would finally open up a script after clicking the error message, since it didn't before, after looking I noticed it was using a unitiEditor reference, after commenting it it worked.