# I can't build my Unity program due to errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

I can't build my Unity program. I click "Build and Run" and get error:

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
>
> at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in **C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194**
>
> at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in **C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethod**s.cs:97
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

Unity is installed on disk. And by path C:\buildslave\unity\build.... I don't have anything.

Comment: What happens if you do "Build" instead of "Build and Run"?

Comment: I get other error:   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors

  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194 

  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: with:       Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194428/unityeditor-buildplayerwindowbuildmethodexception)

Comment: no  answer from  "dublicate"  helped

Comment: there usually are some more helpfull errors more above in the console ... please add those to your question. The two you added only are the final 2 errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen a lot of different answers, but in my case, when building to Standalone, it turned out **I left the game running from the previous build** and it was preventing the new build from creating an executable.

Same 2 errors [0x00242] and [0x0007f].
**I just had to close the game...**