# How to resolve incompatible Gradle Daemon Error causing build failure

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle, build, sdk

I created a new project (Unity) and I switched the platform, PC to Android, from project settings but, when I want to build the project I am getting a Gradle build error, and the oder error which you can see from photos. There is no code, script or anything new; it's just an empty project and I have all of these errors.

[image: THİS PHOTO SHOW MY ERROR JUST CLİCK (:]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to build In unity : "UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194428/unable-to-build-in-unity-unityeditor-buildplayerwindowbuildmethodexception)

Comment: @Ibnelaiq I hate this duplicate ^^ It is extremely broad and missleading ^^ The threre displayed errors can be the result of **anything** making the build fail it only says the build failed but .. there is no information whatsoever **why** it did. Therefore all the answers in that duplicate are just wild guesses and shots into the dark ;)

Comment: However OP [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58664053/7111561) might actually be your specific case?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to uninstall your current version and using unity LTS. May be 2020.3.16f1 version will fit you. You are having trouble with the JDK (Java Development kit) installed on this version. Just try another version, that's all

Comment: İ don't know if i have correct jdk,sdk,ndk version how can i understand it?

Comment: You can go to `Edit - Preference - External Tools`, you will see the location of your JDK, android SDK tool, android NDK tool and gradle installed with unity. Just use the default setting by ticking check in all tools.

Answer (score 0):

Project should be on the disk C, way to project without spaces and only on English language. Try to delete users/User/.gradle and users/User/.android