# Can't export my Unity project as an html5

Tags: html, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, export

I'm trying to export my game as an html5, but everytime I keep getting the same error message:

**UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors

at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <11d97693183d4a6bb35c29ae7882c66b>:0

at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <11d97693183d4a6bb35c29ae7882c66b>:0

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
**

I have tried changing the settings, but the **build ** folder they created is empty.I just want it to give me an html file.

Comment: Is the compression algorithm set to Brotli by any chance? Some really cryptic errors can also occur if you have foreign characters or spaces in the data path.

Comment: No, my compression algorithm is disabled.

Comment: Unfortunate, but it was worth a shot, since those are common. Anyway, what version of Unity are you using and are any unusual addons involved?

Comment: There is a similar 'ish question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194428/unable-to-build-in-unity-unityeditor-buildplayerwindowbuildmethodexception) perhaps a solution from there works for you as well.

Comment: Are there other errors further up in the console? The ones you show here usually only say "there were errors" .. but it isn't the error itself that caused that build to fail .. there should be more details in other error logs